# RxJS forkjoin isn't running

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I am attempting to use RxJS via `rx-http-request` to query third party APIs from a NodeJS server. In the long run, I want to use RxJS to handle some of the more interesting error cases. But for the time being I am having issues getting a fairly trivial case to run.

Case 1 (this works):

```
third_party.js
import {RxHttpRequest} from 'rx-http-request'
export default ((name) => RxHttpRequest.get(`www.third.party.com/${name}`)
```

And then,

```
   import third from './third_party'
   third('bob').subscribe(console.log)
```

Case 2(this does not)

```
   import third from './third_party'
   import Rx from 'rx'
   Rx.Observable.forkJoin(third('bob')).subscribe(console.log)
```

Case 1 prints the (correct) third party response. Case 2 doesn't appear to ever run at all. When I print out console.log(`Rx.Observable.forkJoin`) it prints `Function`, e.g. I have in fact included the right part of Rx.

Case 3:
In thirdParty:

```
export default ((name) => RxHttpRequest.get(`www.third.party.com/${name}`).map((res)=>console.log(res))
```

The inner console.log triggers, but the outer subscribe does not.
Why is this behaviour happening? And how can I actually send the values into the outer subscribe?

Comment: Does `third('bob')` emit `complete`? `forkJoin` needs the inner observable to complete before it forwards something, as it only emits the last message from the inner observable.

Comment: Also, use `do` for side-effects, like `do(e => console.log(e))`

Comment: how can I check if complete is emitted? And how can I force it to complete emit if its not?

Comment: You can do `third('bob').subscribe(e => console.log("next: " + e), err => console.log("error: " + err), () => console.log("complete"))`

Comment: To force it to complete, you need to decide when it will complete. The simplest way would be to do `third('bob').take(1)` i guess.

Comment: I have already tried appending .take(1) to no effect...

Comment: What about `Rx.Observable.forkJoin(Rx.Observable.of("bob"))`, does that run?

Comment: Yes it does. Interestingly Rx.Observable.forkJoin(Rx.Observable.of(third("bob"))) produces TypeError: Object is not iterable.

Anyway, I give up for now, gotta get this out the door. Using .zip instead of .forkJoin, while semantically quite clearly not correct, appears to work...

Comment: `zip` and `forkJoin` are very similar, in fact `zip(source)` and `forkJoin(source.last())` should be the same.

Comment: Oops i meant: `zip` and `forkJoin` are very similar, in fact `forkJoin(source)` and `zip(source.last())` should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing `rx-http-request` like this:

```
import { RxHttpRequest } from 'rx-http-request';
```

You likely installed it like this:

```
npm install --save rx-http-request
```

And you might not have noticed this warning message:

> npm WARN deprecated rx-http-request@1.2.0: This package is no longer maintained and was moved to @akanass/rx-http-request.

That version (1.2.0) is way behind the version that's in the GitHub repo (2.3.0).

Try using `@akanass/rx-http-request`, instead:

```
npm install --save @akanass/rx-http-request

import { RxHR } from '@akanass/rx-http-request';
```

The export appears to have changed, so you should consult the [docs](https://github.com/njl07/rx-http-request#super-simple-to-use).

Also, you should take some care with `rx-http-request`, as it includes `rxjs` as a [dependency](https://github.com/njl07/rx-http-request/blob/master/package.json#L51-L56), rather than a peer dependency. This opens the possibility of multiple `rxjs` packages being installed (depending upon versions and installation order). I would encourage you to [raise an issue](https://github.com/njl07/rx-http-request/issues/new) to have it changed to a peer dependency.

Comment: Thanks for that! The above didn't actually solve my problem per se, but instead found a different problem that I didn't know about :)